# Is a number written in the square root/fraction form called a non-integer even if it can be simplified to an integer

Tags: square-numbers

This is very simple question, but I cannot get the ansewer from the internet.

Is a number written in the square root/fraction form called a non-integer even if it can be simplified to an integer.

For example 4/2, 12/4, sqr4, sqr64 etc... do these need to be simplified before we can call them integers.

Too make this easer to understand are sqr64 and 12/4 non-integers while 8 and 3 are integers.

Comment: $\frac 42=2$ so that's an integer, however you have written it.  Similarly for the others.

Comment: Integers is a subset of Rational numbers, Of course an integer is also a rational number. So the point is no!

Comment: Thank you to all.

Comment: I know this put on hold because its unclear, but everyone who has answered this question seems to understand what I am saying, so I don't see where the problem is. Could you elaborate

Comment: @AsanRamzan I'm surprised the question was put on hold; I've voted to reopen it. Do you feel you have a better understanding after reading the answers?

Comment: @Théophile Yes I understand now,

Answer (score 4):

No.  Numbers are what they are.  It doesn't matter how they are represented.

$7$ is an integer.  Period.

It doesn't matter if is written as $5 + 2$ or $\sqrt{49}$ or $\sqrt{25} + \frac{\sqrt[3]{16}}{2^{\frac 13}}$ or $\ln (e^7)$.

Those are all equal to $7$ and $7$ is an integer.  Period.

====

That said, it might not be easy (or even possible) to tell if a number is or is not an integer.  It's obvious that $7$ is an integer and $7.0000012142650469991421281354411.....$ isn't.  But it isn't clear whether $\sqrt[7]{823543}$ or $\sqrt[7]{823544}$ are integers.  (It turns out that those are the same numbers.)

But it doesn't matter whether we *know* if a number is an integer or not.   It either is or isn't.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ is an integer. $4/2$ is equal to $2$, and therefore has all the properties that the number $2$ has, including being an integer. The square root of $4$ is also equal to $2$, so it's an integer as well. In some cases, you'll probably need to simplify to recognize that it is indeed an integer, but that doesn't change its properties no matter how you write it.

For example, is $\sqrt{14883}$ an integer? How about $\sqrt{14884}$? It might be tough to tell unless you do the simplification, but one is an integer and one isn't.

Answer (score -4):

If it can be simplified to an integer,
it can be called an integer
*after* the simplification.

Until the simplification is done,
I would just call the expression
"an expression"
when it is not clear if it could be
simplified to an integer.

Considering how expressions
involving nested radicals
can be sometimes
amazingly simplified,
I think that there would be cases
where the fact that
an expression simplifies
to an integer
is a surprise.

Comment: I disagree.  The number either is or is not an integer whether we know whether it is or is not.  So it *IS* an integer before we simplify it.  It's just that before we simplify it we don't *KNOW* if it is an integer.  But that doesn't mean it isn't an integer.  (because ... it is.)

Comment: Suppose the expression encodes something we don't know the answer for - for example, 1 if $\pi$ is a normal number, 1/2 if it is not. Is the value of the expression an integer?

Comment: " Is the value of the expression an integer?"  If $\pi$ is normal then it is an integer. If $\pi$ is not normal it is not an integer.  The fact that we don't *know* if it's an integer or not doesn't prevent it from being an integer or a non-integer.

Comment: No. A normal number is a real number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: Um.... What are you *talking* about??? Of course normal numbers are real numbers.  Everything that isnt complex is a real number.  You asked if given the function $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is normal; $f(x)$ if $x$ is not normal.  You asked whether $f(\pi)$ is an integer (which it is if it is $1$) or if it was not an integer (which it will not be if it is $\frac 12$).  And the answer is: We don't know.  But *EITHER* $f(\pi)$ is an integer OR it is not.  We can NOT say $f(\pi)$ is a non-integer, just because we don't know that it is an integer. We don't know it is not.

Comment: "Suppose the expression encodes something we don't know the answer for"  Then we don't know the answer for it.  That's all.  That doesn't mean the answer is "No".  It means the answer is either "Yes" or "No" but not both and not neither, but we do not and probably never will know which.  All numbers are either an integer, or a non-integer. And it doesn't matter how we express them.  The fact that we don't *KNOW* which some numbers are doesn't mean they aren't either.